# Procedural City Generator

Tags: python, maya, mel

Say I have made some building models already. Is it possible to generate some sort of city from those buildings using Python/MEL?

If so, how do I go about it? I was thinking of making like 20 houses and then randomly place them on a square plane so that it would make a city scene.

Comment: This information is by far not enough to answer your question. Also, posts on StackOverflow are expected to be specific programming problems and demonstrate some prior effort to solve the problem.  Please consider revising.

Comment: it's not very difficult to randomly place and scale objects using MEL or Python.  However StackOverflow expects you to start with a piece of code to show what you've tried.  You might want to try someplace more end-user specific like  http://tech-artists.org

Answer (score 2):

There are always multiple ways to do it: using [Paint Effects' Brushes](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-FBB8499C-8C6B-4887-A69D-5E4B3D910D84-htm.html) or [MASH Replicator Node](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-34E5E335-898B-4BB4-89E7-49807CB5E9EA).

Also look at [Python City Generator](https://github.com/stevenquinn/CityGen) by Steven Quinn and [MEL City Generator](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzahJa2QOOWuazdQSjNCYVFBU00/view) by Luca De Nardi.

Comment: Just an update, I'm Luca De Nardi and my MEL City Generator is now available at the following link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzahJa2QOOWuazdQSjNCYVFBU00/view?usp=drivesdk&resourcekey=0-NxtRSGzBFSQJXunbTIr7_Q